# Trying to deleting from Active Record collection ONLY using delete_if

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to remove elements from an Active Record collection, for this I'm trying to use delete_if. Below is my collection:

```
categories = Category.all
groups = Group.all

  result = []
  groups.each do |g|
    result.push({ :name => g[:name], :amount => g[amount_column], :drilldown => [] })
    categories.where( { :group_id => g.id } ).each do |c, index|
      result.last[:drilldown].push({ :name => c[:name], :amount => c[amount_column], :drilldown => nil })
    end
    # lastly, remove these categories from this collection (not working)
    categories.delete_if {|c| c.group_id == g.id }
    # tried this too - categories.select! { |c| c.group_id != g.id }
  end

  abort(categories.size.inspect)
```

..I want to do something with the categories of each group, then remove them form the array. After the loop block I'll want to be left with the categories which do not belong to a group - that is why I delete those of each group there. Here is the data for groups and categories when they are first fetched (sorry it's a lot but just to note that some category.group_id and group.id match:

```
#categories
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Category id: 13, name: "Internet", user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-03-09 13:15:19", updated_at: "2014-03-15 05:13:47", amount: #<BigDecimal:7f0c283806e0,'0.0',9(18)>, group_id: nil, amount_in: #<BigDecimal:7f0c28380578,'0.0',9(18)>, amount_out: #<BigDecimal:7f0c283804b0,'0.0',9(18)>>, #<Category id: 15, name: "Electricity", user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-03-09 13:15:39", updated_at: "2014-03-15 05:14:03", amount: #<BigDecimal:7f0c2838f5a0,'0.0',9(18)>, group_id: nil, amount_in: #<BigDecimal:7f0c2838f460,'0.0',9(18)>, amount_out: #<BigDecimal:7f0c2838f2f8,'0.0',9(18)>>, #<Category id: 6, name: "Phone", user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-02-18 10:07:47", updated_at: "2014-03-15 05:16:21", amount: #<BigDecimal:7f0c2838e470,'0.0',9(18)>, group_id: nil, amount_in: #<BigDecimal:7f0c2838e308,'0.0',9(18)>, amount_out: #<BigDecimal:7f0c2838e240,'0.0',9(18)>>, #<Category id: 9, name: "Trains", user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-02-22 03:08:08", updated_at: "2014-03-15 05:16:21", amount: #<BigDecimal:7f0c2838d340,'-0.5E3',9(18)>, group_id: nil, amount_in: #<BigDecimal:7f0c2838d138,'0.0',9(18)>, amount_out: #<BigDecimal:7f0c2838cf08,'-0.5E3',9(18)>>, #<Category id: 5, name: "Resaurants", user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-02-17 12:12:44", updated_at: "2014-03-15 05:16:21", amount: #<BigDecimal:7f0c2839be18,'-0.235E3',9(18)>, group_id: 16, amount_in: #<BigDecimal:7f0c2839bc38,'0.0',9(18)>, amount_out: #<BigDecimal:7f0c2839baa8,'-0.235E3',9(18)>>, #<Category id: 14, name: "Gas", user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-03-09 13:15:27", updated_at: "2014-03-15 05:16:21", amount: #<BigDecimal:7f0c2839a680,'0.0',9(18)>, group_id: 16, amount_in: #<BigDecimal:7f0c2839a3d8,'0.0',9(18)>, amount_out: #<BigDecimal:7f0c2839a1d0,'0.0',9(18)>>, #<Category id: 3, name: "Snowboarding", user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-02-11 09:43:52", updated_at: "2014-03-15 05:16:21", amount: #<BigDecimal:7f0c28398d30,'-0.1111E4',9(18)>, group_id: 16, amount_in: #<BigDecimal:7f0c28398b28,'0.0',9(18)>, amount_out: #<BigDecimal:7f0c28398a38,'-0.1111E4',9(18)>>]>

# groups
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Group id: 16, name: "Testing", user_id: 1, amount: #<BigDecimal:31c0ce8,'-0.1346E4',9(18)>, created_at: "2014-03-09 13:48:50", updated_at: "2014-03-15 05:35:57", amount_in: #<BigDecimal:31d3118,'0.0',9(18)>, amount_out: #<BigDecimal:26b9728,'-0.1346E4',9(18)>>, #<Group id: 17, name: "test", user_id: 1, amount: #<BigDecimal:31d2a88,'0.0',9(18)>, created_at: "2014-03-15 05:38:36", updated_at: "2014-03-15 05:39:00", amount_in: #<BigDecimal:31d14f8,'0.0',9(18)>, amount_out: #<BigDecimal:2e4e650,'0.0',9(18)>>]>
```

.. but my delete_if does nothing (abort shows the same size with or without the delete_if). Please note that there are group.id = 16, and category.group_id = 16 so the delete_if should delete those ones - but it doesn't. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This will update categories in place, selecting all categories with group_id not equal to g.id.

```
categories.select! { |c| c.group_id != g.id }
```

Comment: No. I want to fetch all the categories, then I loop through groups and do something with the categories in that group. When I'm done with that group, I want to remove those categories from the collection. The above is a simplified version, sorry. So, I really want to delete them from this collection using a query. Delete_if?

Comment: You should add that to the question, because most of what you just wrote wasn't in your question. I've updated my answer to hopefully help you out.

Comment: Sorry. I thought perhaps I was using delete_if wrongly so I just simplified it. I've included the full block now. Hope it is clearer now what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If the only thing not working is the `delete_if`, try my updated answer.

Comment: I tried that too, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I still get the same number at the end (when I do size on categories, which should exclude the unwanted ones). I output the following - abort(categories.select! { |c| c.group_id != 16 }.inspect) - but this shows an array of categories with c.group_id = nil AND c.group_id = 16 so it doesn't seem to take into consideration the group_id condition.

Comment: I've been running this over and over and it continues to work for me. What version of ruby are you using? I'm using 2.0.0.

Comment: When I hard code the arrays, such as `categories = [ {id: 1, group_id: 16}, {id: 2, group_id: 17}, {id: 3, group_id: nil}, {id: 4, group_id: 18} ]` and `groups = [ {id: 16}, {id: 17} ]`, it works. I can see however in `abort()` that these array object and an ActiveRecord collection are different types(Outputs - #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Category..?). Is there an issue with my condition for comparing ActiveRecord attributes from standard arrays? Btw I'm using version 2.0.0 also (ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux])

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49832/discussion-between-user3265472-and-jken13579)

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,I think it will help

```
categories.delete_if {|x| x.group_id==16}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but I tried your suggestion but just got the same result. I've updated my question as I perhaps didn't provide enough information.